# rsyslog drops messages excessively

Tags: centos, performance, rsyslog

We have a CentOS machine acting as our syslog server.  I recently noticed that the machine has been dropping large numbers of syslog messages at times.  We have over 250 routers and switches, as well as firewalls logging every connection open / close.

I can see the messages get to the ethernet NIC... for instance, suppose I go into config mode on one of our routers and then exit... this generates a syslog message, and I sniff to demonstrate that it gets to the syslog server...

```
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$ sudo tshark -V udp and port 514 and host 214.110.12.246
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on eth0
Frame 1 (151 bytes on wire, 151 bytes captured)
    Arrival Time: Apr 26, 2013 06:05:33.490721000
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 1
    Frame Length: 151 bytes
    Capture Length: 151 bytes
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ip:udp:syslog]
Ethernet II, Src: 50:57:a8:9f:68:3c (50:57:a8:9f:68:3c), Dst: Supermic_30:4a:07 (00:30:48:30:4a:07)
    Destination: Supermic_30:4a:07 (00:30:48:30:4a:07)
        Address: Supermic_30:4a:07 (00:30:48:30:4a:07)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Source: 50:57:a8:9f:68:3c (50:57:a8:9f:68:3c)
        Address: 50:57:a8:9f:68:3c (50:57:a8:9f:68:3c)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Type: IP (0x0800)
Internet Protocol, Src: 214.110.12.246 (214.110.12.246), Dst: 214.110.16.4 (214.110.16.4)
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00)
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
        .... ..0. = ECN-Capable Transport (ECT): 0
        .... ...0 = ECN-CE: 0
    Total Length: 137
    Identification: 0x0096 (150)
    Flags: 0x00
        0.. = Reserved bit: Not Set
        .0. = Don't fragment: Not Set
        ..0 = More fragments: Not Set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 250
    Protocol: UDP (0x11)
    Header checksum: 0xcf52 [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad : False]
    Source: 214.110.12.246 (214.110.12.246)
    Destination: 214.110.16.4 (214.110.16.4)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 63873 (63873), Dst Port: syslog (514)
    Source port: 63873 (63873)
    Destination port: syslog (514)
    Length: 117
    Checksum: 0x1ed8 [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
Syslog message: LOCAL7.NOTICE: 187: .Apr 26 06:05:32.476 CDT: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by admin on vty0 (214.110.26.29)
    1011 1... = Facility: LOCAL7 - reserved for local use (23)
    .... .101 = Level: NOTICE - normal but significant condition (5)
    Message: 187: .Apr 26 06:05:32.476 CDT: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by admin on vty0 (214.110.26.29)

^C1 packet captured
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$
```

However, that message does not show up in the syslog (even though another message sent at 05:37:05 does)...  Only one of of seven or eight of those messages show up in the log file...

```
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$ pwd
/var/log/net
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$ grep CONFIG network.log
Apr 26 05:08:59 somedevice.company.local 779476: Apr 26 05:08:58.604 
CDT: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by cbutler on vty0 (214.110.31.65)
Apr 26 05:37:05 w9-idf-lab 182: .Apr 26 05:37:04.452 CDT: 
%SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by admin on vty0 (214.110.26.29)
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$
```

I have tried many things to make this server log correctly...

- Removed all extraneous files from the partition
- Checked the NIC for discards / errors
- Reloaded rsyslogd
- Reloaded the system
- `yum update`
- Started a caching nameserver
- Checked iostat (load is quite reasonable, see below)
- Checked vmstat (load again, is quite reasonable)

I'm running out of ideas... how can I stop this server from bleeding syslogs?

---

## MISC Output

Directory listing

```
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$ ls -al
total 3292356
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root      20480 Apr 26 05:17 .
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root       4096 Apr 21 03:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Apr 19 04:22 daily
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  185081020 Apr 26 06:21 fw1.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1936049300 Apr 26 04:15 fw1.log-20130426
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    7629110 Apr 26 06:21 fw2.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  160792210 Apr 26 04:17 fw2.log-20130426
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     118327 Apr 26 06:20 network.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    1572210 Apr 26 04:17 network.log-20130426
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      73108 Apr 26 06:21 wireless.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     686104 Apr 26 04:17 wireless.log-20130426
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$
```

`rsyslog.conf`

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514


$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

if $msg contains 'APF-3-RCV_UNSUPP_MSG' then /dev/null
&~

if $msg contains 'FWSM-2-106007' then /dev/null
&~


if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.225.201' then /var/log/net/fw1.log
&~
if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.225.202' then /var/log/net/fw1.log
&~

if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.19.246' then /var/log/net/fw2.log
&~
if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.19.253' then /var/log/net/fw2.log
&~

if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.5.10' then /var/log/net/fw_other.log
&~

if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.6.254' then /var/log/net/fw_other.log
&~
if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.6.253' then /var/log/net/fw_other.log
&~

if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.46.254' then /var/log/net/fw_other.log
&~
if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.46.253' then /var/log/net/fw_other.log
&~

if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.19.42' then /var/log/net/fw_other.log
&~

if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.3.203' then /var/log/net/fw_other.log
&~

if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.84.2' then @214.110.16.6
if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.84.2' then /var/log/net/wireless.log
&~
if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.84.4' then @214.110.16.6
if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.84.4' then /var/log/net/wireless.log
&~
if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.70.8' then @214.110.16.6
if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.70.8' then /var/log/net/wireless.log
&~
if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.70.12' then @214.110.16.6
if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.70.12' then /var/log/net/wireless.log
&~
if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.70.16' then @214.110.16.6
if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.70.16' then /var/log/net/wireless.log
&~
if $fromhost-ip=='214.110.16.6' then /var/log/net/wireless.log
&~

if $fromhost-ip startswith '214.110' then /var/log/net/network.log
&~
if $fromhost-ip startswith '214.111' then /var/log/net/network.log
&~
if $fromhost-ip startswith '214.112' then /var/log/net/network.log
&~


*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

*.emerg                                                 *

uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

$template SpiceTmpl,"%TIMESTAMP%.%TIMESTAMP:::date-subseconds% %syslogtag% %syslogseverity-text%:%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"

:programname, startswith, "spice-vdagent"       /var/log/spice-vdagent.log;SpiceTmpl
```

`iostat 5`... these numbers are typical... the load doesn't spike that much...

```
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$ iostat 5
Linux 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.i686 (uglylogger.local)  04/26/2013      _i686_  (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2.25    0.05    0.80    0.37    0.00   96.52

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda              10.67       364.09       536.25  995468936 1466172104
dm-0             33.82        15.35       268.50   41981146  734110616
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00       3056          0
dm-2              2.21         0.05        17.60     132282   48114080
dm-3             33.07       348.68       250.14  953334658  683895008

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.05    0.00    0.00    0.15    0.00   99.80

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               1.00         0.00         8.00          0         40
dm-0              0.80         0.00         6.40          0         32
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-3              0.20         0.00         1.60          0          8

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.05    0.30    0.00   99.65

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               1.00         0.00        33.60          0        168
dm-0              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-3              4.20         0.00        33.60          0        168

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.05    0.00    0.30    0.20    0.00   98.44

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               1.20         0.00         8.00          0         40
dm-0              0.80         0.00         6.40          0         32
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-3              0.20         0.00         1.60          0          8

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.40    0.00    0.30    0.15    0.00   98.14

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               0.80         0.00         6.40          0         32
dm-0              0.80         0.00         6.40          0         32
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-3              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.05    0.00    0.05    0.25    0.00   99.65

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               5.40         0.00        46.40          0        232
dm-0              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-3              5.80         0.00        46.40          0        232

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.05    0.15    0.00   99.80

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               0.80         0.00         4.80          0         24
dm-0              0.60         0.00         4.80          0         24
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-3              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           3.71    0.00    1.05    0.10    0.00   95.14

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               1.20         0.00        19.20          0         96
dm-0              1.40         0.00        11.20          0         56
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-3              1.00         0.00         8.00          0         40

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.05    0.00    0.00    0.35    0.00   99.60

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               3.40         0.00       102.40          0        512
dm-0              1.40         0.00        11.20          0         56
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-3             11.40         0.00        91.20          0        456

^C
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$
```

`vmstat 5`...

```
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$ vmstat 5
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  1      0 240408  50068 3506120    0    0    46    67    2    2  2  1 97  0  0
 0  0      0 240400  50068 3506152    0    0     0    19 1312   37  0  0 100  0  0
 1  0      0 239160  50084 3508648    0    0     0    18 3943 2320 20  6 74  0  0
 1  0      0 242632  50100 3510084    0    0     0   212 3561 2718 14  5 81  1  0
 0  0      0 238168  50116 3510336    0    0     0    58 1612 2537  1  1 98  0  0
 0  0      0 235440  50124 3510340    0    0     0   510 1340 1333  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 235564  50132 3510340    0    0     0    19 1470   37  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 235564  50140 3510344    0    0     0    28 1348   40  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 235440  50156 3510340    0    0     0    17 1497   37  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 235564  50156 3510348    0    0     0    70 1522   38  0  0 100  0  0
```

`df -h`...

```
[mpenning@sasmars net]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_uglylogger-LogVol01
                       73G   17G   56G  23% /
tmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             985M  126M  809M  14% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_uglylogger-LogVol00
                       20G  655M   18G   4% /home
/dev/mapper/vg_uglylogger-LogVol03
                      592G  4.9G  557G   1% /var
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$
```

`netstat -s`...

```
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$ netstat -s | head
Ip:
    452407434 total packets received
    0 forwarded
    0 incoming packets discarded
    449256489 incoming packets delivered
    156718754 requests sent out
    150 reassemblies required
    75 packets reassembled ok
Icmp:
    2423436 ICMP messages received
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$
```

`ifconfig eth0`...

```
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$ ifconfig eth0 | grep -E "dropped|collisions"
          RX packets:466065257 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:252751047 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$
```

`ethtool -S eth0|grep -vw 0`...

```
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$ sudo ethtool -S eth0|grep -vw 0
NIC statistics:
     rx_packets: 5206242266
     tx_packets: 255859804
     rx_bytes: 1205016281115
     tx_bytes: 180592917566
     rx_broadcast: 15001736
     tx_broadcast: 2648
     rx_multicast: 7518499
     tx_multicast: 50236
     multicast: 7518499
     rx_no_buffer_count: 103
     tx_restart_queue: 1
     tx_tcp_seg_good: 10107428
     rx_long_byte_count: 1205016281115
     rx_csum_offload_good: 5189768707
     rx_csum_offload_errors: 5
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$
```

`lspci`...

```
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation E7501 Memory Controller Hub (rev 01)
00:00.1 Unassigned class [ff00]: Intel Corporation E7500/E7501 Host RASUM Controller (rev 01)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation E7500/E7501 Hub Interface B PCI-to-PCI Bridge (rev 01)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation E7500/E7501 Hub Interface C PCI-to-PCI Bridge (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801CA/CAM USB Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801CA/CAM USB Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801CA/CAM USB Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 42)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801CA LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801CA Ultra ATA Storage Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801CA/CAM SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:1c.0 PIC: Intel Corporation 82870P2 P64H2 I/OxAPIC (rev 04)
01:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82870P2 P64H2 Hub PCI Bridge (rev 04)
01:1e.0 PIC: Intel Corporation 82870P2 P64H2 I/OxAPIC (rev 04)
01:1f.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82870P2 P64H2 Hub PCI Bridge (rev 04)
02:01.0 RAID bus controller: 3ware Inc 7xxx/8xxx-series PATA/SATA-RAID (rev 01)
03:02.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82546EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 01)
03:02.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82546EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 01)
04:1c.0 PIC: Intel Corporation 82870P2 P64H2 I/OxAPIC (rev 04)
04:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82870P2 P64H2 Hub PCI Bridge (rev 04)
04:1e.0 PIC: Intel Corporation 82870P2 P64H2 I/OxAPIC (rev 04)
04:1f.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82870P2 P64H2 Hub PCI Bridge (rev 04)
05:02.0 Serial controller: 3Com Corp, Modem Division 56K FaxModem Model 5610 (rev 01)
07:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Rage XL (rev 27)
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$
```

`uname -a`...

```
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$ uname -a
Linux uglylogger.local 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Mar 12 21:42:46 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
[mpenning@uglylogger net]$
```

Comment: A bug in rsyslogd, where it receives a line but doesn't write it to the logfile? Is that already rsyslog-7.3.12?

Comment: It's `rsyslogd 5.8.10`... I'm not sure if it's exposed to that bug... do you have a link to the specific bug?

Comment: No, that bug was an assumption from me. 5.8.10 is rather old tho, can you try a newer version?

Comment: Please update your answer with the output of `ethtool -S eth0|grep -vw 0` as this will show more detailed statistics about what has been happening on your network card.

Comment: @ott, it seems like you were right about a bug in rsyslogd...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update to the newest version of rsyslog.  We had this exact problem at work, and that's the only thing that solved it.    The earlier version(s) had issues with name resolution, and even turning it off didn't solve it.  The 7.x branch solves the problem.   I'll see if I can find the specific link.

Comment: I found some of my old emails.  Here is a bit of an explanation as to why it's dropping packets - http://kb.monitorware.com/udp-packets-arrive-but-are-missed-rsyslog-t10841.html.  The problem is with reverse name resolution, and at some point the "-x" flag was introduced to turn off name resolution.  In version 7, the bug is fixed so you can keep name resolution AND get your packets - http://blog.gerhards.net/2011/06/full-blown-dns-cache-for-rsyslog.html.  The last post is from the blog of the author of rsyslog.

Comment: I can not believe that RedHat did not backport that fix. They normally do. The version-number does not say how many backport-fixes are included.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that RedHat did backport all performance-related problems to the rsyslog-version contained in the operating system.

`rx_no_buffer_count: 103` seems to be the core problem here.

This says that there have been 103 TCP-packets that were dropped BEFORE they could be passed to the operating system.

The drop was registred in the NIC (and not passed to the OS, so `netstat` did not show this). To solve the problem you will propably have to increase the receive-ring-buffer size in your NIC-settings.

Do a `ethtool -g eth0` to see your current and possible settings for RX.

From my experience setting the RX-ring-buffer to 2048 or 3172 is pretty good.

This will give the NIC time to buffer incoming TCP-packets until the hardware (this needs a PCI-interrrupt) and the OS has time to process the packets.

Here is a explantion from [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-network-common-queue-issues.html), what is going on here.

To make this change persistent, change ETHTOOL_OPS like described [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html).

Comment: Hi Nils, thank you for pointing out the TCP drops... honestly, that number is so tiny compared to the number of syslog messages we were dropping I'm not so sure this is in the critical path of solving the major focus of the question.   I will look at tuning NIC buffers through

Comment: @MikePennington Just my guess. I updated my answer with two links for further reading. Ask the network-guys about the port-error-statistic for the port where your server is attached, too (and update your question with the findings).